MDS2016: Is It Possible to Create Dependent Relationships Between Entities?
I am wondering if the following is possible in Microsoft MDS2016. I have a list of customers, and for each customer, I want to define four levels with a structure name, L1 through L4. I have created a separate entity called "Structures," where I first select a customer from the Customer entity and then create a structure name. What I want to do now is go back to the Customer entity and choose the structure that I created for that specific customer. However, at the moment, I am seeing all structures, including those from other customers. If I select "Heineken" as the customer, I only want to see the structures that I created under "Heineken" in the Structure entity. Do you know if this is possible? I'm looking for a way to create a relationship so that dependencies are established between the domain attributes, in this case, a relationship between the customer and the structure.
